# Push Notifications without APNS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I work perfectly with Push Notifications for iOS using APNS. So for some customers, I need an on-premise or local solution, where I could send notifications to the device without APNS and without dependence on the internet. Somebody knows? can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. You cannot get  notification from APNS without internet.

What you can do to accomplish this is you send message from your server to the app while it is in background mode and generate local notification accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 14 this is available through [Local Push Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/local_push_connectivity), but you will require the App Push Provider entitlement that you must apply for specifying why you are unable to use APNS.

Apple sample code is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/local_push_connectivity/receiving_voice_and_text_communications_on_a_local_network).

Answer (score 1):

Let me clarify your question.

"Locally" means: you got either no internet connection, a local network without connection to APNS OR the users simply did not register for push notifications.

**1. iBeacon with Local Push Notification**

So, here is an alternative, and that's kind of NOT what it is basically used for, but as you may know. iBeacons can be used to transport small data chunks, very very small ones. If your users did enable location services, you could include these for your application to trigger certain events (in this case, a very small notification that users came into range of a point of interest).
Downside: The application bundle requires either a static "notification text" to beacon mapping or you have to dynamically download the mapping from a web source, so you could update the notification's text.

**2. Bluetooth with Local Push Notification**

Another alternative would be to use bluetooth instead.
Devices could auto connect to your Bluetooth Station "Peripheral" - These devices now (with the help of your app) would register to a broadcasting characteristic of your Peripheral.
The peripheral could send messages to the registered devices.
If now the device does receive such a broadcasted message, you could perform a local push. - Without any network connection, just with the help of bluetooth, which itself also requires user permissions, of course.

**3. Internet Connection / Silent Push with Local Push Notification**

If your application of course had a working internet connection, you could avoid the APNS from Apple and send your own notifications to the device as silent push notifications.

Comment: But with connection possibility to local servers for data updates or not?

Comment: For example: I need to send notifications to the application I developed for my users, without an internet connection, only on the local network. Can I do this via VPP with MDM?

Comment: An enterprise distribution (as VPP) should work with this case. Make sure the devices are registered at your MDM if you want to deploy the app to their devices. As an alternative you could also make an "Appstore"-like deployment, were users can download and install the app to their devices

Answer (score 0):

`APNS` works only with internet. If you need to push a message to the user without internet one solution (*probably only solution currently*) is using SMS api. But that requires user mobile number. Using `URL Schema` the user can open your app from the SMS message.

Comment: How to use **URL Schema** in iOS using swift language, can you please share the reference link.